# Is there a way to reset a daily task to skip its upcoming schedules after few executions and reset for the next day?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a task which runs every 5 mins for 30 mins (7 executions daily). It basically calls an SP which in turn checks for fresh data in few tables then calls another SP only if all the tables has fresh data. This check happens for 30 mins only everyday (credit consumption restriction). Sometimes it happen that on the 1st run itself it finds fresh data in all tables and then triggers the SP but then after 5 mins the task runs again till 7th time, which is creating issues and absolutely unnecessary.

Now how do I avoid all the upcoming schedules of the task for the day and reset its schedule to the next day, once any of the run is successful for that day?

Comment: How is a check for new data and not doing anything if none is found "causing issues"?

Comment: If you are appropriately using streams to indicate "fresh data" and you have your tasks checking using the WHEN clause, then you could run those tasks every 5 minutes...period...and it wouldn't cost you anything.  It will just run when there is data...and not run when it doesn't.

Comment: The thing is I am not using streams so no when clause in task, but using the load_history table to check for each table load on each day. @MikeWalton

Comment: You should use streams instead.  Much easier.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
After reading some comments above, I agree that adding a stream to your table is likely a better option than my thoughts below. I can't say 100% that it will work for your case because I don't know all the details of how your table is loaded, but I suspect it could work very well. Some resources on Streams [Here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stream.html)

Would be happy to answer questions and fill in more details on how you could implement a stream if you can provide more detail on how your source tables are loaded. Perhaps with simplified example tables.

---

I can think of a couple semi-hacky options.

A) your stored procedure can certainly run an alter task suspend query to stop the task for the day. The weird part is then you need something to restart it, which would need to be... a separate task that only runs once a day, specifically to restart your task's schedule.

It's kind of weird, and gives you an extra minor task to maintain, but it would work. And if it's a serverless task it wouldn't use any warehouse or resources, since the `alter resume` is a metadata operation.

B) There's a few variations on this other idea: you could have your procedure check the time to figure out if it's the first of the day, and truncate a dummy table. Then have it check if there's any records in the table (obviously won't be for the first run). Then once it's successful have it insert into that dummy table (so that presence of any records means that it's run today)

after a successful job, the task will only run a `select count(*)` and then stop and that would be considered metadata so it won't even spin up a warehouse, and if you use serverless tasks, your task will also not spin one up and use very minimal resources.

You could certainly evolve this a bit by using an actual log table that has useful information instead of a dummy table. And it's possible that just switching to serverless tasks will give you the credit consumption reduction that you're looking for.

Sidenote: to try serverless tasks, just remove the warehouse definition from your create task statement.